# Prevent an event happened in Shiny if no UI inputs are available

Tags: r, user-interface, error-handling, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to know how to prevent an event happened if no UI inputs are available. In the following example, there is an action button called `Add UI`. The idea is the users can click that button and add a numeric input as many times as they want. They can then input numeric values. When they are ready, they can click the `Sum` button. The total of these numbers would be the input value for the "Total" numeric input.

However, if the users click the `Sum` button before adding any UIs, the app will stop. I would like to make the `Sum` button clickable even there are no added UIs, keeping the input value of the "Total" numeric input to be `0`.

A relared question about how to calculate the sum of added UI inputs is from here: [Refer to the Updated UI Input ID and Calculate the Sum in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54522298/7669809)

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add UI"),
  actionButton("sum", "Sum"),

  # Input as the sum
  numericInput(inputId = "Total", label = "Total", value = 0)

)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = numericInput(paste0("txt", input$add), label = "Number", value = 0)
    )
  })

  Num_In <- reactiveValues(
    Total_In = 0
  )

  total_input <- reactive({Num_In$Total_In})

  observeEvent(input$sum, {
    num_names <- names(input)[grepl("^txt", names(input))]

    Num_In$Total_In <- sum(sapply(num_names, function(x) input[[x]]), na.rm = TRUE)

    updateNumericInput(session = session,
                       inputId = "Total", 
                       value = total_input())
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple `if` condition work? You can check if object `num_names` length is equal to `0`:

```
if (length(num_names) == 0) {
  foo <- 0
} else {
  foo <- sum(sapply(num_names, function(x) input[[x]]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

This snippet checks if length is `0` and assigns `0` or uses `sum` over `num_names`.

Full `observeEvent` code:

```
observeEvent(input$sum, {
  num_names <- names(input)[grepl("^txt", names(input))]

  if (length(num_names) == 0) {
    foo <- 0
  } else {
    foo <- sum(sapply(num_names, function(x) input[[x]]), na.rm = TRUE)
  } 
  Num_In$Total_In <- foo

  updateNumericInput(session = session,
                     inputId = "Total", 
                     value = total_input())
})
```