# How to format the numericInput in Shiny with updated UI?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, format, shiny-reactivity

The following working example is derived from my earlier question [Prevent an event happened in Shiny if no UI inputs are available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55579248/7669809). Now I want to format the `numericInput` field with commas to assist the users to read large numbers. I followed the example of Option 2 from this post "https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/barbara/format-numbers/" to change the `Total` `numericInput` with this style. The key is to create a `.js` file that formats the numbers and stores it in a `www` directory under the same folder as the shiny script.

This works nicely with the `Total` numericInput. However, how can I use the same format for those updated, later added `numericINputs`? The challenge is I am not able to know how many `numericInput` would be added later, so it is difficult to modify the `format_numbers.js` file if I don't know the inpur ID to add to that file.

The `format_numbers.js` is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Helper function to guarantee cross-browser compatibility
  // adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16157942
  function localeString(x, sep, grp) {
    var sx = (''+x).split('.'), s = '', i, j;
    sep || (sep = ',');            // default separator
    grp || grp === 0 || (grp = 3); // default grouping
    i = sx[0].length;
    while (i > grp) {
      j = i - grp;
      s = sep + sx[0].slice(j, i) + s;
      i = j;
    }
    s = sx[0].slice(0, i) + s;
    sx[0] = s;
    return sx.join('.');
  }

  // To change Total's input field (lose arrows and other functionality)
  $('#Total')[0].type = 'text';

  // To format the number when the app starts up
  $('#Total').val(localeString($('#Total').val()));

  // To format the number whenever the input changes
  $('#Total').keyup(function(event) {
    $(this).val(localeString($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')));
  });
});
```

The shiny script is as follows.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Modify tags
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "format_numbers.js")),

  # Action button to add numeric input
  actionButton("add", "Add UI"),
  actionButton("sum", "Sum"),

  # Numeric Input
  numericInput(inputId = "Total", label = "Total", value = 0),

  # Text output
  "The number is ", 
  textOutput(outputId = "out_num", inline = TRUE)

)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

  # Add numeric input
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = numericInput(paste0("txt", input$add), label = "Number", value = 0)
    )
  })

  # Reactive values for Total
  Num_In <- reactiveValues(
    Total_In = 0
  )

  # Convert number to character
  # This is to fill in the Total numeric input formatting with comma
  total_num_as_char <- reactive({format(Num_In$Total_In, big.mark = ",", trim = TRUE)})

  total_input <- reactive({Num_In$Total_In})

  observeEvent(input$sum, {
    num_names <- names(input)[grepl("^txt", names(input))]

    if (length(num_names) == 0) {
      foo <- 0
    } else {
      foo <- sum(sapply(num_names, function(x) input[[x]]), na.rm = TRUE)
    } 
    Num_In$Total_In <- foo

    updateNumericInput(session = session,
                       inputId = "Total", 
                       value = total_num_as_char())
  })

  # Convert input to numeric
  total_num <- reactive({as.numeric(gsub(",", "", input$Total))})

  # Create text output
  output$out_num <- renderText({total_num()})
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the following works.

When a UI component is added with `insertUI`, the JS event `shiny:bound` is triggered. Then we can take advantage of that:

```js
  // Helper function to guarantee cross-browser compatibility
  // adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16157942
  function localeString(x, sep, grp) {
    var sx = (''+x).split('.'), s = '', i, j;
    sep || (sep = ',');            // default separator
    grp || grp === 0 || (grp = 3); // default grouping
    i = sx[0].length;
    while (i > grp) {
      j = i - grp;
      s = sep + sx[0].slice(j, i) + s;
      i = j;
    }
    s = sx[0].slice(0, i) + s;
    sx[0] = s;
    return sx.join('.');
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
  // To change Total's input field (lose arrows and other functionality)
  $('#Total')[0].type = 'text';

  // To format the number when the app starts up
  $('#Total').val(localeString($('#Total').val()));

  // To format the number whenever the input changes
  $('#Total').keyup(function(event) {
    $(this).val(localeString($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')));
  });
});

$(document).on('shiny:bound', function(evt){
  var id = evt.target.getAttribute('id');
  if((/^(txt)/).test(id)){
    var selector = '#' + id; 
    $(selector)[0].type = 'text';
    $(selector).val(localeString($(selector).val()));
    $(selector).keyup(function(event) {
      $(this).val(localeString($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')));
    });
  }
});
```

Now, in R:

```
unformat <- function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))
```

and

```
  observeEvent(input$sum, {
    num_names <- names(input)[grepl("^txt", names(input))]

    if (length(num_names) == 0) {
      foo <- 0
    } else {
      foo <- sum(sapply(num_names, 
                        function(x) unformat(input[[x]])), na.rm = TRUE)
    } 
    Num_In$Total_In <- foo

    updateNumericInput(session = session,
                       inputId = "Total", 
                       value = total_num_as_char())
  })
```

Comment: This for your help. This solution looks promising. I have upvoted your answer. After changing the `js` and the R script with your updates, the added numeric input fields still display numbers without commas. Could you check if this solution works on your machine again?

Comment: @www Weird. I have checked again and yes, this works. E.g. `1111` is automatically changed to `1,111`.

Comment: I agree it should work. I feel like I have the same code as your solution. The only difference could be the location of the `unformat` function, but it should not matter. I edited my post and put the `js` and `shiny` code. If you don't mind, could you check if the codes work on your machine? Thank you so much.

Comment: @www Have you tried to put the function `localeString` outside the `$(document).ready(function() {......})` ? Otherwise I'm not sure it is defined in the `$(document).on('shiny:bound', ......`.

Comment: It works. As you said, my `js` script was not correct. Thank you very much for looking into this.